# jcrop not working

Tags: javascript

I can't get jcrop to work

It gives

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).Jcrop is not a function

on $('#image1').Jcrop({

alert($('#image1').value) gives undefined

```
    $form['file1'] = array(
            '#type' => 'file', 
    '#name' => 'browse_file1',      
        '#id' => 'browse_file1', 
    '#attributes' => array('onchange' => 'JavaScript: fileSelectHandler1();'),      
    '#prefix' => '<div class="image-row1">
                    <p class="row-title">Add images to your listing</p>
                    <div class="form-row image-row">
                        <span>image path name</span>',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );




$form['file6'] = array(
            '#type' => 'file', 
    '#name' => 'browse_file6',      
        '#id' => 'browse_file6',  
    '#attributes' => array('onchange' => 'JavaScript: fileSelectHandler(browse_file6, image6);'), 
    '#prefix' => '<div class="image-row6">
                    <p class="row-title">Add images to your listing</p>
                    <div class="form-row image-row">
                        <span>image path name</span>',
    '#suffix' => '</div>
                    <div class="existing-images">
                        <div id="the_image1" class="existing-image">
                            <a href="" class="delete">X</a>
                            <img name="image1" id="image1" src="" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div id="the_image2" class="existing-image">
                            <a href="" class="delete">X</a>
                            <imgname="image2" id="image2"  src="" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div id="the_image3" class="existing-image">
                            <a href="" class="delete">X</a>
                            <img name="image3" id="image3" src="" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div id="the_image4" class="existing-image">
                            <a href="" class="delete">X</a>
                            <img name="image4" id="image4"  src="" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div id="the_image5" class="existing-image">
                            <a href="" class="delete">X</a>
                            <img name="image5" id="image5"  src="" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div id="the_image6" class="existing-image">
                            <a href="" class="delete">X</a>
                            <img name="image6" id="image6"  src="" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>',
    );
```

Am I not defining the images properly as the jquery files are all in the right order? Thanks

Comment: Basically all i want included in my form is 6 <input type="file"> that uses jcrop and display them in 6 different <img>'s but it isn't working and it is giving

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).Jcrop is not a function

Answer (score 1):

If Jcrop is not a function, I would say either...

1. You have not added the jcrop library to the header correctly. Are you using a jcrop module, or adding it yourself?
2. You have the incorrect version of JQuery, try [JQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update)
3. Try changing all your instances of the "$" shortcut to "jQuery"
4. Enclose all your jQuery code in a function with jQuery as a parameter and the $ shortcut

Answer (score 0):

There turned out to be two versions of one of the jquery files